# sql stored procedure Update Valor Com valor do registo anterior na mesma tabela

Tags: sql-server, funções, sql-select, sql-update, stored-procedures

Tenho uma Tabela com varias nomes repetidos sequenciados por uma outra coluna que se chama id2 onde cada 1 desses registos tem uma coluna com uma quantidade 
Exemplo :

Nome-Quantidade-Valor2-id2

teste1-1000-0-1

teste1-1100-100-2

teste1-1100-0-3

teste1-1100-0-4

teste1-1100-0-4

teste1-1100-0-4

Ou seja deve haver um Procedure onde tenho de ir buscar a "Quantidade" anterior somar o "Valor2" actual e gravar registo após registo
Qualquer resposta que possa ajudar agradeço.

Comment: A tabela possui chave primária? Se sim, qual o nome da coluna? 
No exemplo, a coluna id2 apresenta valores repetidos; isto está correto?

Comment: Não esta correcto, publiquei um exemplo talvez mais claro abaixo

Comment: Me parece que há contradições nos objetivos: "buscar a Quantidade anterior somar o Valor2 actual" com "somar QuantidadeAnterior + QuantidadeActual - Valor2". Poderia verificar?

Comment: E quando o valor de id2 for 1, em que não há quantidade anterior, o que fazer?

Comment: pois esse também é um problema em php tenho algo do género a limitar a primeira query em que diz que 

    ...#### where id2>1#### = primeira query
    ...#### where ... #### = segunda query

Comment: Vide http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180842/como-escrever-um-store-procedure-que-usa-valores-da-linha-atual-e-da-anterior/181261