# Como escrever um store procedure que usa valores da linha atual e da anterior?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Tenho a Seguinte tabela,

```
    #    id     #   dataTmp     #   referencia  #nProduz#nStock #   id2 #necessi#
    #   115237  #   31-01-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   6   #   0   #
    #   115238  #   01-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   7   #   0   #
    #   115239  #   01-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   8   #   0   #
    #   115240  #   01-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   9   #   0   #
    #   115241  #   02-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   10  #   0   #
    #   115242  #   02-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   11  #   0   #
    #   115243  #   02-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   12  #   0   #
    #   115244  #   03-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   13  #   0   #
    #   115245  #   03-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   14  #   0   #
    #   115246  #   03-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   15  #   0   #
    #   115247  #   04-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   16  #   0   #
    #   115248  #   04-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   17  #   0   #
    #   115249  #   04-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   18  #   0   #
    #   115250  #   05-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   19  #   0   #
    #   115251  #   05-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   20  #   0   #
    #   115252  #   05-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   21  #   0   #
    #   115253  #   06-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   22  #   0   #
    #   115254  #   06-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   23  #   0   #
    #   115255  #   06-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   24  #   0   #
    #   115256  #   07-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   25  #   0   #
    #   115257  #   07-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   26  #   0   #
    #   115258  #   07-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   27  #   0   #
    #   115259  #   08-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   28  #   0   #
    #   115260  #   08-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   29  #   0   #
    #   115261  #   08-02-2017  #   VL03280103  #   0   #   0   #   30  #   0   #
    #   115262  #   30-01-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   7290    #   1   #   0   #
    #   115263  #   30-01-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   7290    #   2   #   0   #
    #   115264  #   30-01-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   7290    #   3   #   0   #
    #   115265  #   31-01-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   4   #   0   #
    #   115266  #   31-01-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   5   #   0   #
    #   115267  #   31-01-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   6   #   0   #
    #   115268  #   01-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   7   #   0   #
    #   115269  #   01-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   8   #   0   #
    #   115270  #   01-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   9   #   0   #
    #   115271  #   02-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   10  #   0   #
    #   115272  #   02-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   11  #   0   #
    #   115273  #   02-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   12  #   0   #
    #   115274  #   03-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   13  #   0   #
    #   115275  #   03-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   14  #   0   #
    #   115276  #   03-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   15  #   0   #
    #   115277  #   04-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   16  #   0   #
    #   115278  #   04-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   17  #   0   #
    #   115279  #   04-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   18  #   0   #
    #   115280  #   05-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   19  #   0   #
    #   115281  #   05-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   20  #   0   #
    #   115282  #   05-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   21  #   0   #
    #   115283  #   06-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   22  #   0   #
    #   115284  #   06-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   23  #   0   #
    #   115285  #   06-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   24  #   0   #
    #   115286  #   07-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   25  #   0   #
    #   115287  #   07-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   26  #   0   #
    #   115288  #   07-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   27  #   0   #
    #   115289  #   08-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   28  #   0   #
    #   115290  #   08-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   29  #   0   #
    #   115291  #   08-02-2017  #   VL03280203  #   0   #   0   #   30  #   0   #
```

Preciso Que com um Stored Procedure Efectue o seguinte calculo:

```
nStock(RowActual)= nStock(RowAnterior) + nProduz(RowActual) - necessidade(RowActual)
```

Já fiz vários códigos e não consigo por isto a funcionar , alguém me pode ajudar ?

Comment: Como ficará o caso da primeira linha, uma vez que não há linha anterior?

Comment: Deve ser executado sempre começando pela Segunda ... nunca pela primeira ...

Comment: Para que possas calcular o valor da linha atual e de uma linha anterior, vai precisar usar um cursor, já tentou desta forma?

Comment: já tentei, no entanto ainda não consegui, ainda :)

Comment: Qual versão do SQL Server você está usando? No 2012 foi introduzida a função [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh231256.aspx) que retorna dados de uma linha anterior. Nas versões anteriores o *workaround* geralmente envolte dois *left joins* (para *n *e *n - 1*) usando uma função de rankeamento como [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx). Veja [alguns exemplos](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/25/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement-part-4/).

Comment: Aquele ID sempre estará em ordem e sem vazios como o exemplo?

Comment: Você quer que sua stored procedure calcule de todos de uma vez ou você vai passar o id da linha atual e ela só vai atualizar essa?

Comment: O "ID2" é sempre incrementado de acordo com a referencia , enquanto o "ID" é auto-increment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bruno, o problema que você propõe me parece semelhante (mas não idêntico) ao de emissão de extrato de conta bancária, onde para calcular o saldo do dia deve-se obter o saldo do dia anterior, somar os créditos do dia e subtrair os débitos do dia.

A massa de dados que postou como exemplo me parece que não é útil para testar as soluções propostas, pois a maioria das colunas que entram na fórmula estão zeradas. Por isso optei por criar uma massa de dados própria, para testes, que está ao final desta resposta.

**PREMISSAS**
Na análise da amostra da tabela, observa-se que sempre que o valor da coluna `referencia` é alterado, o contador sequencial da coluna `id2` é reiniciado. Presumo então que o valor de estoque deve ser recalculado individualmente para cada valor da coluna `referencia`, tendo como sequenciamento a coluna `id2`. Por isso que, nas soluções propostas, utilizo o par (`referencia`, `id2`) como chave de pesquisa.

Nos comentários você cita que o cálculo de `nStock` deve iniciar da segunda linha; entendo que seja de cada valor da coluna `referencia`. Então, estou assumindo que o valor da coluna `nStock`, sempre que `id2` for 1 (primeira linha), está correto.

---

**SOLUÇÃO 1**

A primeira solução que proponho utiliza [CTE recursiva](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186243.aspx). O código é bem simples.

```
-- código #1 v3
with estoqueAtual as (
SELECT id, dataTmp, referencia, id2, nStock, nProduz, necessidade,
       novoStock= nStock
  from SeguinteTabela
  where id2 = 1
union all
SELECT T2.id, T2.dataTmp, T2.referencia, T2.id2, 
       T2.nStock, T2.nProduz, T2.necessidade,
       (T1.novoStock + T2.nProduz - T2.necessidade)
  from estoqueAtual as T1
       inner join Seguintetabela as T2 
                  on T1.referencia = T2.referencia and T1.id2 = (T2.id2 -1)
)
SELECT id, Convert(char(10), dataTmp, 103) as dataTmp, referencia, id2, 
       nStock, nProduz, necessidade, novoStock
  from estoqueAtual
  --where dataTmp >= 
  order by referencia, id2;
```

Para você testar com a tabela do banco de dados, substitua o texto `SeguinteTabela` pelo nome real da tabela.

---

Eis o resultado obtido ao utilizar a massa de dados criada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Para atualizar a tabela, o código #1 é ligeiramente modificado, substituindo o SELECT final por UPDATE:

```
-- código #3 v2
with estoqueAtual as (
SELECT id, dataTmp, referencia, id2, nStock, nProduz, necessidade,
       novoStock= nStock
  from SeguinteTabela
  where id2 = 1
union all
SELECT T2.id, T2.dataTmp, T2.referencia, T2.id2, T2.nStock, T2.nProduz,
       T2.necessidade, (T1.novoStock + T2.nProduz - T2.necessidade)
  from estoqueAtual as T1
       inner join Seguintetabela as T2 
                  on T1.referencia = T2.referencia and T1.id2 = (T2.id2 -1)
)
UPDATE T4
  set nStock= T3.novoStock
  --output deleted.id, deleted.nStock, inserted.nStock
  from estoqueAtual as T3
       inner join SeguinteTabela as T4 on T3.id = T4.id
  where T4.nStock <> T3.novoStock
        --and T3.dataTmp >=
```

Para você testar com a tabela do banco de dados, substitua o texto `SeguinteTabela` pelo nome real da tabela.

---

**SOLUÇÃO 2**

A segunda solução utiliza outra abordagem. O resultado é o mesmo do código #1.

```
-- código #4 v2
SELECT T1.id, T1.dataTmp, T1.referencia, T1.id2, 
       T1.nStock, T1.nProduz, T1.necessidade,
       novoStock= case when T1.id2 = 1
                       then T1.nStock
                       else ((SELECT nStock 
                                from SeguinteTabela as T2
                                where T2.referencia = T1.referencia
                                      and T2.id2 = 1) +
                             (SELECT Sum(nProduz - necessidade) 
                                from SeguinteTabela as T2
                                where T2.referencia = T1.referencia
                                      and T2.id2 > 1
                                      and T2.id2 <= T1.id2)
                            )
                  end
  from SeguinteTabela as T1
  --where T1.dataTmp >=
  order by T1.referencia, T1.id2;
```

Para atualização, o código #4 é transformado como CTE, ficando então:

```
-- código #5 v2
with estoqueAtual as (
SELECT T1.id, 
       novoStock= case when T1.id2 = 1
                       then T1.nStock
                       else ((SELECT nStock 
                                from SeguinteTabela as T2
                                where T2.referencia = T1.referencia
                                      and T2.id2 = 1) +
                             (SELECT Sum(nProduz - necessidade) 
                                from SeguinteTabela as T2
                                where T2.referencia = T1.referencia
                                      and T2.id2 > 1
                                      and T2.id2 <= T1.id2)
                            )
                  end
  from SeguinteTabela as T1
  --where dataTmp >=
)
UPDATE T4
  set nStock= T3.novoStock
  --output deleted.id, deleted.nStock, inserted.nStock
  from estoqueAtual as T3
       inner join SeguinteTabela as T4 on T3.id = T4.id
  where T4.nStock <> T3.novoStock;
```

---

Eis o código que gera a massa de dados para testes.

```
-- código #2
CREATE TABLE SeguinteTabela (
  id int, dataTmp date, referencia varchar(20), 
  nProduz int, nStock int, id2 int, necessidade int);

set dateformat dmy;
truncate table SeguinteTabela;
INSERT into SeguinteTabela values 
  (115262, '30-01-2017', 'VL03280203', 20, 100, 1, 5),
  (115263, '30-01-2017', 'VL03280203', 30, 0, 2, 10),
  (115264, '30-01-2017', 'VL03280203', 25, 0, 3, 100),
  (115265, '31-01-2017', 'VL03280203', 35, 0, 4, 0),
  (115266, '31-01-2017', 'VL03280203', 40, 0, 5, 120),
  (115267, '28-01-2017', 'VL03280303', 20, 0, 1, 0),
  (115268, '29-01-2017', 'VL03280303', 30, 0, 2, 10),
  (115269, '30-01-2017', 'VL03280303', 20, 0, 3, 18);
go
```

Comment: Para complementar: o máximo de recursão padrão no SQL Server é de 100 interações. Caso a tabela tenha mais que isso será necessário setar a opção `maxrecursion` para o tamanho desejado (0 é infinito) `option (maxrecursion 0)`

Comment: obrigado agora apenas tenho de por a data >= hoje , apenas para actualizar partir do dia actual para a frente sendo que para tras está actualizar com base em outra condição é perfeita a query ... era a vertente que iria criar depois de estudar a primeira opção a cima , muito obrigado

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida: Acrescentei a solução 2, que utiliza abordagem não recursiva. Baseado nas mesmas premissas.

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida: No caso de limitar por data, sugiro então o uso da solução 2. Observe que a cláusula WHERE foi acrescentada.

Comment: Ola , penso que a solução 1 funciona perfeitamente ainda não tive oportunidade de experimentar devido a falta de tempo mas vou fazelo o quanto antes , penso que 
ao acrescentar o seguinte
    where T4.nStock <> T3.novoStock AND dataTmp>=(select dateadd(dd,@i, cast(getdate() as date)))  ;
deverá funcionar 
obrigado !

Answer (score 3):

Para realizar o processo que você quer, pode-se utilizar um `cursor` para percorrer as linhas e selecionar o valor anterior, atualizando assim o novo valor:

```
create procedure atualizar
as
begin
  declare @id          int,
          @nStock      int,
          @nProduz     int,
          @necessidade int;

  set nocount on;

  declare cursorEstoque cursor local fast_forward for
    select tb.id,
           isnull(tb.nProduz, 0),
           isnull(tb.necessidade, 0)
      from tabela tb
     order by tb.id;
  open cursorEstoque
  fetch next from cursorEstoque into @id, @nProduz, @necessidade
  while @@fetch_status = 0
  begin
    -- Pega o valor do último registro
    select top 1 @nStock = isnull(tb.nStock, 0) -- Garante que será calculado caso haja linha anterior
      from tabela tb
     where tb.id < @id
     order by tb.id desc;

    if @nStock is not null -- Será nulo caso não tenha linha anterior
    begin
      set @nStock = @nStock + @nProduz - @necessidade;

      update tb
         set nStock = @nStock
        from tabela tb
       where tb.id = @id;
    end;

    fetch next from cursorEstoque into  @id, @nProduz, @necessidade;
  end;
  close cursorEstoque;
  deallocate cursorEstoque;
end;
go
```

Uma outra forma sem precisar do `select` dentro do corpo do `cursor`:

```
create procedure atualizar
as
begin
  declare @id             int,
          @nStock         int,
          @nProduz        int,
          @necessidade    int,
          @nStockAnterior int;

  set nocount on;

  declare cursorEstoque cursor local fast_forward for
    select tb.id,
           isnull(tb.nStock, 0),
           isnull(tb.nProduz, 0),
           isnull(tb.necessidade, 0)
      from tabela tb
     order by tb.id;
  open cursorEstoque
  fetch next from cursorEstoque into @id, @nStock, @nProduz, @necessidade
  while @@fetch_status = 0
  begin
    if @nStockAnterior is not null -- Será nulo caso não tenha linha anterior
    begin
      set @nStock = @nStockAnterior + @nProduz - @necessidade;

      update tb
         set nStock = @nStock
        from tabela tb
       where tb.id = @id;
    end;

    set @nStockAnterior = @nStock;

    fetch next from cursorEstoque into  @id, @nStock, @nProduz, @necessidade;
  end;
  close cursorEstoque;
  deallocate cursorEstoque;
end;
go
```

Um terceiro modo é utilizando uma variável do tipo `table` para armazenar os dados com um sequencial gerado a partir da ordenação na tabela levando em consideração o `id`:

```
create procedure atualizar
as
begin
  declare @dados table(sequencia      int,
                       id             int,
                       nStock         int,
                       nProduz        int,
                       necessidade    int);

  set nocount on;

  insert into @dados(sequencia,
                     nStock,
                     nProduz,
                     necessidade)
  select row_number() over(order by tb.id),
         isnull(tb.nStock, 0),
         isnull(tb.nProduz, 0),
         isnull(tb.necessidade, 0)
    from tabela tb
   order by tb.id;

  update tb
     set tb.nStock = tba.nStock + tb.nProduz - tb.necessidade;
    from tabela tb
         inner join @dados tba on tba.sequencia = (tb.sequencia - 1) -- Pega o anterior, afinal o sequencial não pula nenhum número
end;
go
```

Por que utilizar a tabela e não apenas algo como `id - 1`? Porque com `id - 1` se alguma das linhas for deletada, o `id` terá "buracos", o que fará a lógica errar em algum ponto.

**Observação:** Para utilizar as tabelas altere o nome nas `procedures` pelo nome que você está utilizando no seu banco de dados.

Comment: Quem negativou a resposta pode ficar a vontade pra deixar um comentário sobre o que está errado que assim eu posso corrigir. Negativar sem deixar comentário não faz muito sentido.

Comment: A função lag vai resolver o problema dele sem recorrer a cursores. Cursores em sql server só vale a pena recorrer em último caso. SE a versão de Sql Server for 2012 para cima.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso então poste a resposta com a função `lag`. Não é obrigatório que uma pergunta tenha apenas uma resposta. E além disso minha resposta não está errada, então não vejo o motivo do `downvote`. Ao invés de criticar uma resposta que não está errada você pode oferecer uma que considera melhor. A propósito, a função `lag` não funcionará se você colocar um parâmetro limitando a data, por exemplo, já que ela só funciona no `resultset` em questão. Recomendo a leitura [Quando usar o downvote](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4701/quando-usar-o-downvote)

Comment: muito obrigado, não tenho tido muito tempo mas hoje vou voltar e espero acabar de uma vez por todas este problema, vou experimentar as opcções , Obrigado Sorack a sua resposta, foi esclarecedora

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida disponha. Só um detalhe, a que eu indicaria pra você utilizar é a terceira opção que disponibilizei acima justamente por evitar usar `cursor`

Answer (score 0):

Usar cursores neste caso é uma forma procedural de se pensar em trabalhar com SQL o que pode fazer com que sua procedure fique lenta dependendo de como este cursor é escrito. O melhor é lembrar da teoria dos conjuntos e pensar na sua tabela única como duas tabelas onde a interseção ou `JOIN` se faz com `id = id-1`.

O MS SQL SERVER tem um recurso muito interessante que é o `UPDATE FROM` caso queira atualizar a tabela de dados.

Eu faria uma StoredProcedure com as seguintes consultas. Use-as como necessitar. Estou dando o nome da tabela fonte de `tabela_dados`.

Consulta:

```
-- Para simples consulta

SELECT nStock = RowAnterior.nStock + RowActual.nProduz - RowActual.necessidade
FROM tabela_dados AS RowActual
INNER JOIN tabela_dados AS RowAnterior ON (RowActual.id = RowAnterior.id-1)
```

Update:

```
-- Para atualizar a tabela

UPDATE RowActual SET RowActual.nStock = RowAnterior.nStock + RowActual.nProduz - RowActual.necessidade
FROM tabela_dados AS RowActual
INNER JOIN tabela_dados AS RowAnterior ON (RowActual.id = RowAnterior.id-1)
```

Comment: Se por algum motivo uma linha pela metade for deletada sua resposta irá falhar, afinal ela só considera se o `id` for o número imediatamente abaixo

Comment: Exatamente. Como isso não ficou evidenciado na amostragem da pergunta não tem como saber se isso vai ocorrer. Não sabemos se a amostragem é uma tabela física ou temporária, ou se a mesma permite de exclusão de registros. De qualquer forma isso pode ser contornado com uma tabela temporária ou varável 'TABLE' com um campo 'seq_id IDENTITY' da forma como vc apresentou em sua resposta, porém, eu o faria sem cursor. Cabe ao analista identificar a necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

```
with estoqueAtual as (
SELECT id_Matrix, dataTmp, referencia, id2, nStock, nProduz,         necessidade,turno,
       novoStock= nStock
  from Matrix
  where dataTmp=(select dateadd(dd,0, cast(getdate() as date))) and turno=1
union all
SELECT T2.id_Matrix, T2.dataTmp, T2.referencia, T2.id2, T2.nStock, T2.nProduz,
       T2.necessidade,t2.turno, (T1.novoStock + T2.nProduz - T2.necessidade)
  from estoqueAtual as T1
       inner join Matrix as T2 
                  on T1.referencia = T2.referencia and T1.id2 = (T2.id2 -1)
)
UPDATE T4
  set nStock= T3.novoStock
  --output deleted.id, deleted.nStock, inserted.nStock
  from estoqueAtual as T3
       inner join Matrix as T4 on T3.id_Matrix = T4.id_Matrix
  where T4.nStock <> T3.novoStock and T3.dataTmp >=(select dateadd(dd,0,     cast(getdate() as date)))
  option (maxrecursion 0)
  ;
```

Aqui Está o codigo Final foi só acrescentar a data e passar a necessidade para turno=2 o qual não tinha posto ainda na bd ... 
Neste momento está a funcionar perfeitamente , Muito Obrigado !